# request module POST JSON request using Cookies

Tags: json, node.js, post, request

When I am using curl command or Postman I am getting proper response within 1 sec but request module is going into timeout most of the time, pls help.
I think I need to add code for -c cookie.txt -b cookie.txt'

```
curl https://example.com/cmd -H "Content-Type:application/json" -k -d '{"cmd":{"dlpktenc":{"id":0,"byte0":001,"byte1":532}}} -c cookie.txt -b cookie.txt'
```

request module:

```
var request = require('request');
request = request.defaults({jar: true});
request(
    { method: 'POST',
     uri: 'https://example.com/login',
     form:
       {  user: username, 
          password: password
        },
      rejectUnauthorized: false,

    },
    function( err, res, body ){
if (!err){
    console.log(JSON.parse(body));
    var requestData = {"cmd":{"dlpktenc":{"id":0,"byte0":001,"byte1":532}}};
    request(
    { method: 'POST',
     uri: 'https://example.com/cmd',
    header:{
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    },
     json: requestData,
     rejectUnauthorized: false
},
    function( err, res, body ){
if (!err){
    console.log(body);

} else console.log(err);
}); 
} else console.log(err);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In cURL, `-d` means ([from the man pages, emphasis mine](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html)):

> -d, --data
>
> (HTTP) Sends the specified data in a POST request to the HTTP server,
>   in the same way that a browser does when a user has filled in an HTML
>   form and presses the submit button. **This will cause curl to pass the
>   data to the server using the content-type
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded.** Compare to -F, --form.
>
> ...
>
> See also --data-binary and --data-urlencode and --data-raw. **This
>   option overrides -F, --form and -I, --head and --upload.**

If curl is working with the command you said, you need to send your request the same way:

```
request({
        method: 'POST',
        uri: 'https://example.com/cmd',
        header: {
            // Correct content type
            'content-type': 'x-www-form-urlencoded',
        },
        body: requestData,
        rejectUnauthorized: false
    },
    function(err, res, body) {
        if (!err) {
            console.log(body);
        } else console.log(err);
    }
);
```

Comment: I have modified curl command can you help me with converting -c cookie.txt -b cookie.txt into request

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in sending the body in the request module as an object unless the json option is set as true

```
var requestData = {
    "cmd": {
        "dlpktenc": {
            "id": 0,
            "byte0": 001,
            "byte1": 532
        }
    }
};


request({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost:9007/mbe',
        header: {
            'content-type': 'application/json',
        },
         body: requestData,
        rejectUnauthorized: false,
       //THE NEXT LINE WAS MISSING IN YOUR CODE
        json : true 
    },
    function(err, res, body) {
        if (!err) {
            console.log(body);
        } else console.log(err);
    }
);
```